# DisplayPort out for 2560x1440 screen on MacBook Air (mid 2012)

Tags: 12.04, screen, mac, monitor, displayport

I've got a MacBook Air (mid 2012) and I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 on it and I'd like to use it with a 2560x1440 `Samsung 27" LED SyncMaster S27A850T screen` with a mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable, connected to the Thunderbolt port.

Is that possible?

Does the thunderbolt port work at all on the mba2012? (I know Linux does not support Thunderbolt yet.)

Is it even possible to connect the MacBook air with Ubuntu to a normal HD monitor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this very useful article here:
https://zignar.net/2012/12/20/linux-on-a-macbook-air/‎

There is a paragraph all about Thunderbolt:

> #### The bad and ugly: Thunderbolt
>
> The tldr version is that Thunderbolt support is currently a pain in
>   the ass. It's so bad that in very weak moments I sometimes consider
>   switching to OS X. (Just kidding, I wouldn't do that)
>
> Coldplugging works just fine. If you turn on the notebook with the
>   display connected and don't unplug it until you're done there is
>   nothing to worry about.
>
> Hotplugging doesn't work. If you want to walk around and get back
>   later to the Thunderbolt monitor you're out of luck.
>
> Even worse is that a solution to the issue isn't very likely to appear *ever*.
>   According to Intel developers the kernel does support the
>   Thunderbolt hotplugging just fine.
>   It is the BIOS that gets it all
>   wrong and is sending some *invalid* values.
>   So unless Apple starts to
>   think that properly supporting Linux would be a good idea we'll never
>   see a fix.
>
> Tiny solace: Connecting a regular monitor using a mDP adapter works
>   fine.
>
> There is also an issue that will degrade the performance of the
>   notebook if connected to a Thunderbolt display. But that can be fixed
>   by disabling polling:
>
> **1** `> cat /etc/modprobe.d/drm_kms_helper.conf`
>    **2** `options drm_kms_helper poll=N`